# an 84MB Volume /dev/loop0 popped up and I don't know what it is or why it popped up

Tags: loop-device

So, out of nowhere a 84MB Volume /dev/loop0 popped up. I don't know what it is or why it is there. I did recently install dropbox, Kdenlive, and VLC Media Player. Could one of those programs have caused this? Should I worry? I'm new to Linux. Should I get rid of this Volume, and if so how do I do that?

Comment: @muru do I don't think so. This is asking whether it is a problem, that is asking what it is.

Comment: @ubashu and if you know what something is, you can judge for yourself if it is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have any iso's or other special files "mounted" (look at your file browser on the left). They will usually create loop devices as special mounts.

No, you don't need to worry about it. They can be created by various programs, but 84MB is not large at all.

If you want more info, read this answer: [What is /dev/loopx?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906581/what-is-dev-loopx?rq=1)

If you want to try to remove it for whatever reason, try `umount /dev/loop0`. You might need a `sudo` before `umount` depending on the device.

Comment: You can run `losetup` (with `sudo`) to see the backing file of a loop device. It may have partitions and may not be mounted anyway, so it doesn't make much sense to blindly `umount` it.

Answer (score 1):

From `man loop`:

> The loop device is a block device that maps its data blocks not to a
>   physical device such as a hard disk or optical disk drive, but to the
>   blocks of a regular file in a filesystem or to another  block  device.

As mentioned by Tom Yan, you can find the loop device's backing file (assuming it is indeed backed by a file and not another block device) with `sudo losetup`.

The file path/name might give you a hint as to which application it belongs to.

If it does not, you may have luck with `dpkg -S <file>`