# Why is my server not using the external volume?

Tags: server, 20.04, mount, storage

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server running Nextcloud 19. My server got full, so I mounted a 100GB volume. Here is the output of `df -h`

```
 $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            474M     0  474M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M   11M   88M  12% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   25G     0 100% /
tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           491M     0  491M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.9M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop1       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/16922
/dev/loop2       31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9607
/dev/loop3       31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9721
/dev/loop4      253M  253M     0 100% /snap/nextcloud/24018
/dev/sda        100G   61M   95G   1% /mnt/volume_nyc1_01
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

/dev/sda appears to be mounted correctly, but my server doesn't seem to be using it. When I try to update, it reports there is no space left. How can I make the server use the external volume space? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you instruct your server to use that volume? How?

Comment: I didn't. I just assumed it would make use of it automatically. I later made a folder using the Nextcloud GUI that pointed to that volume, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates involve storing updating/creating files in many different locations. You (or the system) mounted your external drive on `/mnt/volume_nyc1_01` (see [here](https://www.linuxnix.com/what-is-a-mount-point-in-linuxunix/)). As a result, you can now store 100GB of files in that folder. This space, however, is not shared among the entire directory structure of your system. For example, you would not be able to put a file in `/home/username/Desktop` that is 100GB without having space on that drive, even if you do have space in `/mnt/volume_nyc1_01`. `/dev/vda1` is a special file that refers to one of your hard drives (or, more accurately, a partition on one). It is mounted on `/`, meaning that everything on your system (everything starting with `/`) that is not in another partition's mount point is on that partition. Since that disk is full, you can no longer store files in places not mounted from another disk (such as `/mnt/volume_nyc1_01`). Possible ways to utilize this disk space in other places include [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) and mounting a partition in another place, such as `/home/username` or wherever nextcloud needs it. For more information, see my simalar answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284179/can-someone-help-me-understand-what-im-looking-at-and-how-and-what-i-should-use/1284183#1284183).